# A few questions about data.table in r

Tags: r, data.table

So I went over [this](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html) tutorial, and have a few questions:

1. What is the exact meaning of "columns within the frame of a data.table are seen as if they are variables"?
2. Is there a particular meaning for the "L" after 6 in month==6L? (in the data table its only 6 not 6L).
3. I understand how to calculate mean for every column by something, but what if I simply want to calculate the mean of each column (assuming that I have many columns so I don't want to write all the names).

Thanks!

Comment: 3) if you want the mean of every column `DT[, lapply(.SD, mean)]`  2) the `L` is just to denote integer version instead of numeric.  1) I didn't understand the question.

Comment: 1) [See here](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Environment-objects) for an explanation of what's meant (in this context) by "frame".

Comment: I think 2e and 2g answer 3) and 1) in the link you provide in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. expanding the quote: "you don’t have to use DT$ repetitively since columns within the frame of a data.table are seen as if they are variables" referring to variables within a data.table, is like using the `with` function, which minimizes typing and may make lines more readable.
2. "L" is an R marker that says treat the preceding number as an integer (not a numeric (double)).
3. use the .SD method, for example to get the sum of all variables by variable byVariable in data.table dt:

   `myDT <- dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by="byVariable"]`